# use powershell socket server to get remote command

Tags: sockets, powershell

I want use a powershell socket server to get remote command.
But I only can get the remote command once.
Can someone give me a help? thanks.

Here is my code:

```
$endpoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint([system.net.ipaddress]::any, 12346)
$listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
while($true)
{
    $listener.Start()
    $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()

    [System.IO.StreamReader]$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $client.GetStream()
    while($true)
    {
        $line = $stream.ReadLine()
        while($line -ne $null){
            Write-Host $line -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }

    }
    $client.Close()
    $listener.Stop()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can get the remote command once" ? Explain what you are expecting

Comment: I use a client program to send command.
First time I execute the client,the command I send show in powershell normally.
But after second time,command don't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your while check ($line -ne $null) will always be true because $line is not assigned the new value after initial assignment,
try this:

```
$endpoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint([system.net.ipaddress]::any, 12346)
$listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
while($true)
{
    $listener.Start()
    $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()

    [System.IO.StreamReader]$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $client.GetStream()
    while($true)
    {

        do {
         $line = $stream.ReadLine()
         Write-Host $line -ForegroundColor Yellow  
        }while($line -ne $null)


    }
    $client.Close()
    $listener.Stop()
}
```

Comment: @FroceLu what error are you getting ,i tried the above program that i shared and using telnet to connect to port and passed multiple commands and it was accepting

Comment: :Thanks. This is my first post at here,so I don't know the manners and post in wrong way.

Comment: @FroceLu: Not a problem .Enjoy Coding ;)